# how to use composite data types (e.g. geomval) in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgis, raster, geoalchemy

I'm trying to replicate a nested raw PostGreSQL/PostGIS raster query using SQLAlchemy(0.8)/GeoAlchemy2(0.2.1) and can't figure how to access the components of a [geomval](http://postgis.net/docs/geomval.html) data type. It's a compound data type that returns a 'geom' and a 'val'.

Here is the raw query that works:

```
SELECT (dap).val, (dap).geom
FROM (SELECT ST_DumpAsPolygons(rast) as dap FROM my_raster_table) thing
```

And the SQLAlchemy query I'm currently working with:

```
import geoalchemy2 as ga2
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

metadata = MetaData()
my_raster_table = Table('my_raster_table', metadata,
                  Column('rid', Integer),
                  Column('rast', ga2.Raster))

engine = create_engine(my_conn_str)
session = sessionmaker(engine)()

q = session.query(ga2.func.ST_DumpAsPolygons(my_raster_table.c.rast).label('dap'))
```

And then I'd like to access that in a subquery, something like this:

```
q2 = session.query(ga2.func.ST_Area(q.subquery().c.dap.geom))
```

But that syntax doesn't work, or I wouldn't be posting this question ;). Anyone have ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ended up being fairly simple:

First, define a custom **GeomvalType**, inheriting geoalchemy2's **CompositeType** and specifying a **typemap** specific to **geomval**:

```
class GeomvalType(ga2.types.CompositeType):
    typemap = {'geom':ga2.Geometry('MULTIPOLYGON'),'val':Float}
```

Next, use **type_coerce** to cast the **ST_DumpAsPolygons** result to the **GeomvalType** in the initial query:

```
q = session.query(type_coerce(ga2.func.ST_DumpAsPolygons(my_raster_table.c.rast), GeomvalType()).label('dap'))
```

Finally, access it (successfully!) from the subquery as I was trying to before:

```
q2 = session.query(ga2.func.ST_Area(q.subquery().c.dap.geom))
```